# Playwright placing cursor at the end of an input field

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, playwright

I'm using playwright to write my tests. And I have a problem: I need to test the following behaviour:

1. Apply the bold style to some text there's already in my input
2. Check that the text I'm writing after keeps the bold styling.

To do it I need to go to the end of my input field and use the `type` command. How can I go to the end of my input. Here some pseudo-code:

```js
// Before I already applied the bold. It is not relevant for the question.

const input = page.locator(`[data-testid='INPUT_FIELD']`)
await input.focus(); // Focus the input field
/* TODO: Go to the end of the input field [What should I do?] */
await input.type(' remaining part of the message');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always go to the end of the text in your input by using the [`keyboard.press()`](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-keyboard#keyboard-press).

```
const input = page.locator(`[data-testid='INPUT_FIELD']`)
await input.focus(); // Focus the input field
await input.keyboard.press('End')
await input.type(' remaining part of the message');
```

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75563089/6243352) is good, suggesting triggering an <kbd>End</kbd> press. Here's a runnable example that uses `page` instead of `input` for accessing the `.keyboard` property:

```js
const playwright = require("playwright"); // ^1.30.0

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><input value="hello">`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await playwright.chromium.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const input = page.locator("input");
  await input.focus();
  await page.keyboard.press("End");
  await page.keyboard.type(" world");
  await input.screenshot({path: "test.png"});
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

You can also use key left and right to move the cursor to other locations in the input.